# Any open source alternatives to balsamiq mockup

Tags: prototyping, wireframe, mockups

As the title reads, I'm looking for open source alternatives to balsamiq mockup for prototyping. Anyone knows of an equally good alternative that's open source or basically freeware.

Comment: Are you looking for free of charge (freeware, though this word is not well defined), or software with freedom (open source / Free Software) ?

Comment: This is a pretty valid and relevant question to software development and I don't agree with the decision to close it. Maybe we need up/down voting for these decisions to let the community determine if a particular topic is worthy of remaining open. We are about serving the community at stackoverflow aren't we?

Answer (score 64):

The best available Open source mock up tool is Pencil. Its available as firefox plugin as well as [stand alone](http://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/Home.aspx).

Another solution, which I personally use is Inkscape, an open source SVG Editor. It is NOT a mock up designer, but we can use it for designing mock ups, using freely available stencil kit, like [Yahoo Stencil Kit](http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/about/stencils/).

Comment: I'm using Pencil now - the standalone version. It's very comprehensive and solidly built. Just download, make sure you've got xulrunner, and run: xulrunner application.ini

Comment: Well done @hfactor for answering the *question*! :-) Pencil is the best Open Source (GPL) alternative to balsamiq. Maquetta looks promising, but Pencil is mature > http://pencil.evolus.vn/

Comment: I'm using the standalone version of Pencil and it's terribly buggy (as of 2014). Certain elements are not saved, pdf export is terrible, png export is incomplete, gui elements are not configurable/flexible enough.

Comment: Yes, Pencil is buggy, export is cumbersome and I've lost some data, too. Would not use it again.

Comment: The most recent version (2.0.5) is still a bit buggy, but I find it to be the best open source app available before moving to QTCreator or other such heavy apps.

Comment: Does Pencil anyway support the Right to Left languages?! I mean shapes and tables, can we change their direction to be delt with from right to left?

Answer (score 22):

[Mockingbird](https://gomockingbird.com/) is free during beta

Firefox's [pencil](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8487/) add-on is free forever

Comment: Actually, Mockingbird is open source: https://bitbucket.org/gomockingbird/mockingbird/src

Comment: Tried accessing Mockingbird source on BitBucket and got "Access denied". so not quite "open source". By contrast Pencil http://pencil.evolus.vn/ is GPL.

Comment: @niutech Mockingbird isn't open source anymore

Comment: No one can remove an open source license, so if you can get hold of an open source version, you can fork the project. The newer versions (as a whole) may never have been open source. The copyright owner, can duel licence and remove a licence from newer version, but all the original code is still under the old licence.

Comment: The site is listing an old version of Pencil... One of the comments there refers to a new link at github: https://github.com/prikhi/pencil/releases

Comment: where is the old code?

Answer (score 17):

Take a look at **Maqetta**. It runs as a html5 app in your browser, so you can deploy it on your server to easily share your work with others, or you can simply start it locally and point your browser to localhost on port 50000.

On their homepage, you can test maqetta online (after registering), or download a package that contains everything needed to run it locally.

Resources:

- [Homepage](http://maqetta.org/)
- [Repository on github](https://github.com/maqetta/maqetta)

Comment: Maqetta hosted is discontinued from today, and the repository doesn't seem to get much attention anymore

Answer (score 14):

[WireframeSketcher](https://wireframesketcher.com/) is not open-source but it's free for open-source developers. WireframeSketcher helps you quickly create wireframes, mockups and prototypes for desktop, web and mobile applications. It comes both as a **standalone** version and as a **plug-in** for Eclipse IDEs. It has some distinctive features like storyboards, components, linking and vector PDF export. Among supported IDEs are are Aptana, Flash Builder, Zend Studio and Rational Application Developer.

[image: Sample WireframeSketcher mockup]
<sub>(source: [wireframesketcher.com](http://wireframesketcher.com/samples/Website.png))</sub>

Comment: It seems that there's no more a free version

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/when-free-depends-on-nonfree.html

Comment: I cant see any evidence of a free version available to anyone other than bloggers who do a positive review.